# SQL Server Login role for remote database manipulation

Tags: sql-server, funnelweb

My scenarion is MVC Blog (funnelweb) installed on a server named `WEB`. The SQL Server 2005 runs on `DB`. FunnelWeb site requires access to its own database. I have create a new database using SQL Server Management Studio and had named it `FunnelWeb`. I want to use SQL authentication, so I went ahead and created a SQL login `FunnelWebAdmin`. In the login mappings I have mapped `FunnelWebAdmin` to `FunnelWeb` database, and have granted him a dbowner permission on a db. I have not granted a login any server roles.

SQL Authentication is enabled for the server.

My question is:

Do I need to grant this login any server roles, so that the web site can connect to a database using SQL authentication? If yes, which are the minimum one's in order for site to be able to manipulate database.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something setting that user in the role DBAdmin will give it the right to login.  It will give it full rights and control over the database.

Comment: But will it allow a Web site, hosted in IIS on another server to connect to DBMS and use the login to manipulate database?

Comment: Yes, if I'm right, it will.  Hopefully you've got the web site locked down because that design leaves your app wide open for all sorts of attacks.

Comment: Ok. I got the problem figured out. The Login setup is fine, and I am now able to work with the database from the site's code. What do you mean by "open wide"? Is it becuase FunnelWebAdmin is a dbowner on a FunnelWeb database? SQL server is not Internet accessible, so the hacker would need to hack through the web site to get to the data from what I understand.

Comment: Correct.  I changed my comment to an answer and added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something setting that user in the role DBAdmin will give it the right to login. It will give it full rights and control over the database.

Be sure you lock down that web application.  Giving admin rights to a DB from a web app is dangerous at best.  It leaves you open to SQL injection, which can open the door to all sorts of issues.  A good attacker (or a mediocre one with access to google)  can exploit an SQL Injection attack and gain full control over the operating system if the server isn't locked down properly.  http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/doc/BlackHat-Europe-09-Damele-A-G-Advanced-SQL-injection-whitepaper.pdf

Even if they can't get control over the OS, you still need to worry about  data theft, insertion of XSS or XSRF scripts, or any number of attacks.

I'm not saying not to do it, just to be careful and be sure you know what you're doing.  Getting access to a database via a web app is childs play if there are any vulnerabilities.  There are toolkits that you can buy that do it for you, so attackers don't even need to know what they're doing.

**I really have no idea what your experience level is, so forgive me if I'm telling you something you already know.**  Your question indicates that you're more on the "beginner" end of the spectrum, but I may be wrong.

Assuming I'm right, however, I would really caution you to spend a lot of time on these sites,learning everything you can.  They don't teach this stuff adequately in school, or in the "Learning programming" resources (books, web, videos, etc).

[OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main)

[Writing Secure Code (Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570401)

Even if the website itself is not Internet accessible (say it's running on a corporate Intranet and only logged in users have access) you still need to be cautious.  Statistics show that disgruntled co-workers with access are just as much of a threat as outside attackers.  Just something to bear in mind.

Comment: Ok, so I need to lower his permissions to reader/writer I guess. Too bad it's a custom app and I don't know if the sql user need to be able to add tables later.

Comment: Thank you for the links, will review. In most cases I would not need to deal with SQL interactions. I just bumped into this problem because I am setting up a personal blog, the engine of which requires SQL access.

Comment: @Maxim V. Pavlov - OK.  Good luck!